# How to set different global options in knitr and RStudio for word and html?

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

I am using RStudio 0.98.932 and knitr 1.6. Would like to set different global knitr options for word and html. For example, want to set fig.width and fig.height as 6 for word and 11 for html.

I can write some codes to switch the setting if it is available for the output format of a rmd file. How should I do this? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try putting this code chunk at the beginning of the Rmd document.

````
```{r setup, cache=FALSE, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
output <- opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")
if (output=="html") opts_chunk$set(fig.width=11, fig.height=11)
if (output=="docx") opts_chunk$set(fig.width=6,  fig.height=6)
```
````

One of the package options returned by `opts_knit$get()` is `markdown.pandoc.to`. This is evidently set to `"html"`, `"docx"`, or `"latex"` depending on the chosen output format (HTML, Word, or PDF). So you can test that and set the chunk options `fig.width` and `fig.height` accordingly.